# Ubuntu LTS 14.04 tells me to upgrade kernel to 4.4

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, lts

I have installed on my server Ubuntu LTS 14.04 with kernel 3.19 (3.19.0-68-generic) and now when I log in, I see in notification information about **Hardware Enablement Stack** not being supported anymore (EOL). Following link is included - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

So basically I will not receive Kernel updates till I upgrade to 4.4 (which I do not want to) or upgrade to 16.04 (do not want either) ??

Doesn't this kinda break LTS promise? I know they started LTS with weird version 3.19, which is not maintained by anybody in longterm (https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html). Were they really so shortsighted? It really makes u think if you can trust Ubuntu on your server.

Or should I shut up and update to 4.4 anyway? My concern primary is stability cause I am running RAID on server.

Regards,
JIV

Comment: Another consideration is kernel versions automatically installed can be automatically deleted down the road

Comment: What do you meant by that?

Comment: Let's say I manually add Kernel 3.13.x and Ubuntu automatically adds Kernel 3.13.y and 3.13.z.  Sometime down the road Ubuntu might automatically delete 3.13.y and 3.13.z because it automatically installed them. Ubuntu will not automatically delete 3.13.x because I manually added it.